# When using curl to http post a xml file to a url, how to set the parameter?

Tags: ubuntu, curl

I want to use curl to http post a file to a url like:

```
curl -d myfile.xml http://www.example.dom/post/file/here
```

Can I set the parameter I want the file to be posted with?   Like if it was a querystring I would do:  ?file=filedatahere

How do you do that with a post?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can specify parameters via querystring to a resource you are posting to. Also you should use '@' before a filename if the data is being read from a file. So using your example I believe this should look like:

```
curl -d @myfile.xml "http://www.example.dom/post/file/here?foo=bar&this=that"
```